# Как подключить библиотеку, написанную на c# /c++/ c к php скрипту?

Tags: c#, c, php, c++

Как подключить библиотеку, написанную на c# /c++/ c к php скрипту?
Возможно ли это на "стандартном" хостинге, где не очень-то много прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключить в php.ini или в редакторе, который его изменяет. После чего надо перезагрузить сервер.

Если перезагрузка или редактирование произвести невозможно, простыми методами библиотеки вы не подключите.

Как вариант, можно попытаться использовать функцию [dl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php), но гарантировать, что она у вас включена, тоже не могу. Обычно ее блокируют в соответствии с рекомендациями.